# Getting following error while deploying to node react app to heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, react-redux, heroku-cli

[image]

List item

I am trying to deploy a node - react app on heroku

Comment: what is the error ?? check more detail of 503 error

Comment: seems like u trying to make request to weather API. which is not available

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying your app as a node.js application you can run into this issue. Create your heroku app using the create-react-app buildpack: 
https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/mars/create-react-app-buildpack

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

A 503 error code means the server cannot handle the request because it is either unresponsive or overloaded, as stated on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/503?retiredLocale=uk). This could be a result of incorrectly initializing the application on Heroku. Run the following in your directory from the terminal to deploy to heroku.

```
cd  my-project
git init
heroku git:remote -a app-name

git add .
git commit -am "comment"
git push heroku master
```

More details about deploying a Node app to Heroku can be found [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs)